# Pandas - Print multiple dateframes

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a Jupyter notebook, and matplotlib has the option to draw a matrix of plots. Is there a similar option to draw multiple tables (from dataframes) like that? I have like 8 pieces of 2x2 dataframes, which I'd like to print in a 4x2 matrix format.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jupyter notebooks can leverage HTML to diplay results. This may not be the most elegant solution, but this may work...

Set up DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd  
from IPython.display import HTML
%pylab inline
d1=pd.DataFrame(rand(2,2))
d2=pd.DataFrame(rand(2,2))
d3=pd.DataFrame(rand(2,2))
d4=pd.DataFrame(rand(2,2))
```

Display HTML table including your dataframes:

```
HTML("""<table>
<tr>
 <td> {0} </td> <td> {1} </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td> {2} </td> <td> {3} </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 """.format(d1.to_html(),
            d2.to_html(),
            d2.to_html(),
            d3.to_html()))
```